# strip dictionary of {}, "" and : python3

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to know how to strip a dictionary as so

```
>>> dict = {"hello", "world"}
>>> print(dict)
{"hello" : "world", "hi" : "StackOverflow"}
```

how do I make it output

```
hello world
hi StackOverflow
```

Comment: Dictionaries can't be stripped. That doesn't make any sense. You are trying to print some custom output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {"hello" : "world", "hi" : "StackOverflow"}

for i, j in my_dict.items():
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
hello world
hi StackOverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the `dict.items()` and print according to the format you want.

```
for k,v in dict.items():
   print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```